# Azure IoT Hub - Where can I see why the hub disconnects the devices?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm using an Azure IoT Hub. I'm still in the development phase. It used to work fine, but now the hub is disconnecting the devices almost immedially after they connect. Where can I see some logs or info about why the hub is disconnecting? And if I have to activate some services, which ones?

Comment: Please add much clearer details to your question: How do you connect your devices? using the SDK? Which protocol? What messages do you see on the client side when this happens?

Comment: I'm developing the backend, not the front end, so I'm not 100% sure. But I belive the devices use an mqtt library and mqtt protocol. The devices don't see error messages. They just connect and the server disconnects. But basically I need to know where the server logs are.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-monitor-resource-health

Answer (score 0):

You may need to turn on diagnostics for IoT Hub for logging the device connection events and errors. Once the logs and alerts are ON for connected devices, you will get alerts, error logs when errors occur. The troubleshooting link to begin with can be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-troubleshoot-connectivity which captures details about how to enable diagnostics, alerts and other possible troubleshooting methods. This section ['Resolve connectivity errors'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-troubleshoot-connectivity#resolve-connectivity-errors) has description on how to look for common issues when you receive an alert and this seems to have dependency on Azure monitor logs to be enabled. It also furnishes information in terms of problem resolution guides for the most common errors.

There are couple of services integrated with IoT Hub like Azure Monitor and Azure Resource Health that help to provide you with the data required for keeping your IoT solution running in healthy state. Azure Resource Health helps to monitor whether your IoT hub is up and running. Here is a related link on [iot hub health monitor and diagnose problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-monitor-resource-health) that can be a additional reference for you.

Azure Monitor stores log data in a Log Analytics workspace, which is an Azure resource and a container where data is collected, aggregated, and serves as an administrative boundary as conveyed in [Azure monitor logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-platform-logs#what-are-azure-monitor-logs). Data in Azure Monitor Logs is retrieved using a log query written with the Kusto query language, which allows you to quickly retrieve, consolidate, and analyze collected data.